Optimizing PostgreSQL full-text search query with GROUP BY and aggregation
I have a PostgreSQL query that performs a full-text search and then groups and aggregates the results. While the full-text search part is fast (< 1 second), the grouping and aggregation are causing significant slowdown (about 9 seconds total). I'm looking to optimize this query to run in 1-3 seconds. Here's my current query:
SELECT imv.ref_chain_name,
       array_agg(imv.item_name) AS matching_ingredients,
       count(imv.item_name)
FROM ingredients_mv2 imv
WHERE imv.full_text_tsv @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'coca cola')
GROUP BY imv.ref_chain_name

Important details:

The full_text_tsv column contains the full text of a ref_chain_name (including all item names, their descriptions, and modifiers).
Users input search terms (like "coca cola") in real-time, so we can't pre-compute results for specific ingredients.
After the full-text search, we need to group by ref_chain_name and show all matching item_names and their count.
The table ingredients_mv2 is quite large is about 6-8M rows.

I've already ensured that there's a GIN index on the full_text_tsv column, which is why the WHERE clause is fast. The bottleneck seems to be in the GROUP BY and aggregation operations.
I've really tried to think hard about pre-computing some stuff but I can't seem to think how. A user writes down an ingredient (e.g. 'coca cola') and it is only after I've filtered for coca cola that I can count the total number of item names that mentions coca cola in their full text (the full_text_tsv column is a text column with the item_name + description of the plate + additional menu modifiers). I can't precompute this for every single ingredient because there are millions of ingredients. What strategies can I employ to optimize this query for production use?
EDIT:
Here's the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):
HashAggregate  (cost=2306.79..2366.69 rows=2077 width=55) (actual time=10116.826..10172.958 rows=15404 loops=1)
  Group Key: ref_chain_name
  Planned Partitions: 8  Batches: 9  Memory Usage: 1145kB  Disk Usage: 7288kB
  Buffers: shared hit=1689 read=83353, temp read=606 written=1429
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ingredients_mv2 imv  (cost=22.98..2213.13 rows=2172 width=39) (actual time=64.030..9863.038 rows=100113 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (full_text_tsv @@ '''coca'' & ''cola'''::tsquery)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1500010
        Heap Blocks: exact=21211 lossy=61698
        Buffers: shared hit=1689 read=83353
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_full_text_tsv  (cost=0.00..22.43 rows=2172 width=0) (actual time=58.337..58.338 rows=100113 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (full_text_tsv @@ '''coca'' & ''cola'''::tsquery)
              Buffers: shared hit=35 read=58
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=164 read=20
Planning Time: 8.429 ms
Execution Time: 10176.310 ms


Turn on track_io_timing and then show the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the query (as formatted text).

Thanks @jjanes. I was unable to set track_io_timing because the DB owner is digital ocean. Does the EXPLAIN without that work? I've edited the question.

Note that it is not the aggregation which is slow, but reading the table data.
Digital Ocean (I don't use it) should have a way to turn track_io_timing on.  It would be through their management portal, not directly in SQL.  It might only be available on certain tiers.
This could be slow because it had to read 83353 dispersed pages (IO bottleneck), or because of the rechecks (CPU bottleneck).  Without the io timing data, I can't tell but I suspect it is due to IO.
You can try to improve the IO performance by increasing effective_io_concurrency, although the effectiveness would depend on the IO hardware/drivers you are running on.
If it is the rechecks, you could improve that by increasing work_mem to get rid of the lossy pages.
